# While loop produces duplicates - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use the below snippet to retrieve data from Freshdesk - at this stage, testing that params are replaced as expected and what I noticed is that instead of printing just 10 lines, it printed like 30 lines. Any idea why?

```
def data_extraction(url):
    i = 1
    page_num = 10
    while i <= page_num:
        param = { 'page': i, 'per_page': 100}
        formatted_url = furl(url).add(param).url
        i += 1
        print(formatted_url)        
data_extraction('https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets')
```

Current output:
[image]

Comment: I don't see ```furl``` defined anywhere in your script?

Comment: You must be running this code 3 times, there's nothing here that would duplicate it.

Comment: I tried running this, and it prints 10 lines as expected, `page=1..10&per_page=100`

Comment: @eddyizm Looks like it's this: https://github.com/gruns/furl

Comment: No, I am not running it three times )

Comment: thanks @Barmar - Ran it without that library and it only runs 10 times. OP must be calling it more times inadvertently.

Comment: Actually, even if I change it to the below it still runs 30 times:     while i <= page_num:
        param = { 'page': i, 'per_page': 100}
        final_url = '?'.join([url, '&page={page}&per_page={per_page}'])
        formatted_url_max = final_url.format(**param)
        i += 1
        print(formatted_url_max)

Comment: The problem is NOT in this code, it's in the code that's calling it. Something is calling it 3 times.

Comment: Put `print("starting data_extraction")` at the beginning of the function to see how many times it's being called.

Comment: @Barmar, it showed three lines

Comment: That proves you're running it 3 times. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The thing is that I literally just calling the libraries and that code. There is nothing else running.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the whole snippet. I removed the furl library, perhaps, if anything, there is a bug in that library but as per the comments above by @Barmar and @Cavin, it does not run 30 times. I suspect you have it somewhere else in your code being called inadvertently.

EDIT : Added a print to see where in your code it's being called, verifying it's being  called once.

```
        >>> def data_extraction(url):
                print('calling data_extraction function')
                i = 1
                page_num = 10
                while i <= page_num:
                    formatted_url = f'{url}?page={i}&per_page=100'
                    i += 1
                    print(formatted_url)

        >>> data_extraction('https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets')
        calling data_extraction function
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=1&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=2&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=3&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=4&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=5&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=6&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=7&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=8&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=9&per_page=100
        https://yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?page=10&per_page=100
        >>>
```

Comment: Nope, @eddyizm, I copied your code, replaced with the domain, run and still got my beloved 30 rows.

Comment: You should follow @Barmar  recommendation to print where you are calling the function. Also, perhaps post more of your code so we can examine it. As we have all stated, your code and mine only print 10 lines so it's something happening outside of what we can see in the code above.

Comment: I did it and I got three times. There is nothing else to post. I am running just that code

Comment: Was restarting the kernel, it didn't help but weirdly what helped was creating a new notebook and pasting the code there again. idk what happened there.

Comment: voted to close the thread as the root seems to be random and noone could replicate it.